# Can Windows 11 synch data with my Android 'phone?

Tags: sync, data-transfer, windows-11

It seems that [Windows 11 can run Android apps](https://websuggestion.com/can-windows-11-run-android-apps-explained/).   This could, possibly be a major breakthrough, if ...

Until now, I choose apps, such as the [TaskCoach to-do manager](https://www.taskcoach.org/) which run natively on both Windows and Android, then I use DropBox to synch the data files.

Recently, I had problems with this approach, which I won't go into here.

My question is whether the new Windows 11 will obviate the need for DropBox by synching data files between devices, allowing me to add or remove TaskCoach to-dos on one device and have that reflect on the other (e.g laptopn / 'phone).

Comment: The Android feature has been postponed and will be available next year.

Comment: OIC. Do you have a link for that. Have you read anything that might help me anticipate the answer to my question next year? And, do you know when next year? Thanks & upvote

Comment: [Microsoft delays Android app support on Windows 11 into 2022](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-11-android-apps-delayed-2022)

Comment: "`We don't know if Microsoft plans to deliver this feature in an update to Windows 11 version 21H2, or if Microsoft will wait until the next big Windows 11 feature update, version 22H2, currently scheduled for release in fall 2022.`"  :-(